# Get test results with dotnet test on command line

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I created an ASP.NET Core 1.1 xunit test project with the following csproj file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.6</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0- preview-20161123-03" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0-beta4-build3444" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLib\ClassLib.csproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

</Project>
```

I am able to run the project using `dotnet test` using the command line but I don't see any information of how many tests passed or failed.

The version of the Dotnet Command line I am using is:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview4-004124)
```

How can I display the test results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make dotnet-test work, you also need to include a PackageReference to xunit.runner.visualstudio.

By the way, since you posted your question, the format for csproj has been greatly simplified. An xunit test project looks like this (as of Visual Studio 2017 RC, January and dotnet CLI 1.0.0-rc3-004350).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="5.0.0-preview-20170125-04" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0-beta5-build3474" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0-beta5-build1225" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLib\ClassLib.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Os this also valid when using Visual Studio Code with Asp.Net Core 1.1? Or just valid for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Just change the TargetFramework value to netcoreapp1.1